# How to replace symbols by their value in a R function body

Tags: r, function

This code reveals that `f` doesn't yet look up `q` before it's called.

```
q <- 2
f <- function(x) q + x
f
```

I want to tell R which symbols in the body to look up right away (in this case `list("q")`) and have it modify `f` accordingly. How can it be done?

Comment: You either need to pass `q` as a parameter to your function `f` (ie, `f(q,x)`. Or you need to define `q` so that it exists in the workspace (we call this the global environment) before `f` is called or defined.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I think you can also give it its own workspace, like `f = local(function(x) q + x); environment(f)$q <- 10; f(1)` ..? I rarely do this, so I'm not sure if it's a good way to go about it.

Comment: there might be an incantation involving `substitute` and `body(f)`, but I can't work it out ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Common Lisp this would look like:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter q 4)
Q
CL-USER> (let ((bar q))
            (defmacro f (x)
               `(+ ,bar ,x)))
F
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 `(f 4))
(+ 4 4)
T
```

In R this could look like:

```
> q = 2
> f = eval(bquote(function(x) .(q) + x))
> f
function (x) 
2 + x
>
```

Since R is interpreted, eval is par for the course there. With Common Lisp, if you do not want to use eval, you can go with a compile-time macro that carries along with it a hard-coded value for 'q, so that every time it is used in code at that point on it refers to the value of 'q at creation time of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are wrong about what happens when you make an assignment for a token of the value of `function`. Take a look at this:

```
> environment(f)$q
[1] 2
```

Some of the base R function keep values hidden away in the environments of the returned objects. The two that come to mind are `ecdf` and `splinefun`.

Comment: But when the function is called it looks up q in the environment. This wouldn't happen if the function was defined by the code: `f <- function(x) 2 + x`.

Comment: If you don't want to allow the usual workings of R environments and evaluation along the search path, then you need to make an assignment in the body of the function.  Or use the code of Gregory which is having the effects of creating an extra "layer" around the functions each having a local environment containing a specific value of `q`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
f_generator = function(q){
    q
    function(x){
        q + x
    }
}


f2 = f_generator(2)
f3 = f_generator(3)

f2(1)
# 3
f3(1)
# 4
```

Comment: Problem is that `body(f_generator(2))` is NOT `{2 + x}` but it is `{q + x}` so the modification hasn't been applied!